# Inundated with marketing tracking pixels (Campaigns with multiple vendors)!

Tags: google-analytics

We have some third parties that are sending us traffic and have asked us to put a tracking pixel on the confirmation page so they can track through the sales.

We are currently using Google analytics for our own usage.

Google will [remember the original referral](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55540) through cookies. This may be a good or bad thing. If someone purchases through company B's link but they had originally found our site through company A - then company A still gets the 'referal'. That doesn't seem fair, but it seems to be the way google analytics works:

> For example, if this is the user's
>   first visit to your site, the tracking
>   code will add the campaign tracking
>   information to the cookie. If the user
>   previously found and visited your
>   site, the tracking code increments the
>   session counter in the cookie.
>   Regardless of how many sessions or how
>   much time has passed, Google Analytics
>   "remembers" the original referral.
>   This gives Analytics true
>   multi-session tracking capability.

Currently we only have one tracking pixel on our 'receipt page' from a company that we're not even doing business with. Having a second company ask me for us to add one makes me thing 'wait a minute - we're going to suddenly be inundated with these things!'. Plus it means someone can look at the source and see all the people we do business with.

This isn't Oprah - you cant ALL have tracking pixels. Right ?

How should we manage sales from multiple traffic sources in the most honest way for both sides - especially if they already have a system set up that they insist on using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem at our company: we gave our partners a URL that has a parameter in the query string. This parameter triggers a cookie. On the "goal"/confirmation page (where the tracking pixel is usually inserted), we insert some logic to see if the cookie value is correlated with a one of our recognized partners (chained if-else or switch statement). If a match is found, then the tracking pixel is displayed.

Even though you asked this question a while ago, I hope that this still helps you or someone else with the same problem!